# What are the main parts of a Wordpress Template?

Tags: templates, customization

This may sound like a stupid question, but...

What are the main parts of a Wordpress template, and which parts are mandatory and which parts are optional?

So far I am aware of:

- Posts (mandatory)
- Pages (mandatory)
- Page Templates (optional)
- Tags (optional)
- Categories (optional)
- Search / Search Results (mandatory)
- Archives (mandatory)
- Widgets (optional)

Is there anything else?

Comment: You need just [the `index.php` and `style.css`](https://github.com/toscho/Toscho-s-Mini-Theme) and maybe a `comments.php`. Everything else is optional. Why do you think the other parts are required?

Comment: [This is as small](https://github.com/wycks/Smallest-Wordpress-Theme-Ever) as a theme can be while still being able to present infomation. On the other side of the spectrum there are themes with hundreds of files.

Comment: @toscho Because most templates seem to have them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it is as toscho has said. index.php and style.css are the bare minumum.

Developers like to separate things, though, so instead of having one index.php file to rule all, you'll find parts like:

```
header.php
footer.php
sidebar.php
index.php
style.css
functions.php
```

and additional templates like ones you mentioned in the question.

[This page](http://thethemefoundry.com/blog/html-wordpress/) will show you how its done at the minimum level.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include your theme in the WordPress theme repository it should at least include:

1. index.php
2. comments.php
3. style.css

This list and many other best practices can be found on the [Theme Review](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Review#Theme_Template_Files) page in the Codex.